# Masonry space between every two items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently someone asked me if I could put in google adsense in his website. He has a masonry style layout with two posts on each row and a sidebar.

He wanted the ad to be displayed between the first and the second row (see image below)

See image here
[image]

1 = the post in a masonry element column with dynamic width and height

2 = containing div of all post

3 = where the ad should be placed

My initial thought was to try and wrap each row. The container did not hold the absolute masonry elements however.

Secondly i tried giving the container that i had put around every other two posts to get the height from the first item but that didn’t work since i then got the correct height for that container but it didn’t push the second row down either with margin or padding.

Is there any other way that this could possibly be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: "however since the masonry elements are absolutely positioned the relative container won’t contain them" - false. Absolute positioning refers to closest relative positioned parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As phpdna has mentioned, go with the stamp!

```
container.masonry({
    itemSelector: ".item",
    stamp: ".yourAd"
});
```

and then apply the `yourAd` class to your ad's div.

Comment: Thanks bro! Managed to get it working this way :)